# Show month calendar in date time dropdown in OSX?

Tags: macos, calendar

By default OSX shows the date and time in the header menu bar. [image]

When you click on it it shows this:

[image]

Is there a way for it to show the calendar?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the OS-provided menu-bar clock and replace it with itsycal.

https://www.mowglii.com/itsycal/